# Why are different devices/email clients displaying this CSS differently?

Tags: html, css, formatting, html-email

I have a support ticket design in HTML/CSS that seems to malfunction inconsistently when viewed on different devices. On a given web browser on the PC, my code works perfectly. However, when viewed from several different mobile email clients, different parts begin to completely break.
Here is my snippet:

```css
.container {
  width: 700px;
  margin: 100px auto;
}

.progressbar {
  counter-reset: step;
}

.progressbar li {
  /*name of incomplete tasks */
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000000;
}

.progressbar li:before {
  /*circle of incomplete tasks */
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  content: "";
  counter-increment: step;
  line-height: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #535659;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto 5px auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.progressbar li:after {
  /* line preceding incomplete tasks */
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #535659;
  top: 12px;
  left: -50%;
}

.progressbar li:first-child:after {
  content: none;
}

.progressbar li.done {
  /* check mark and name of completed tasks */
  color: #94d60a;
}

.progressbar li.done:before {
  /* circles of completed tasks */
  border-color: #94d60a;
  content: "\2713";
}

.progressbar li.done+li:after {
  /* line following completed tasks */
  background-color: #94d60a;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <div style="width:650px; background-color:#bbbcbc;">
    <header>
      <h1>
        <a style="color:#000000;background-color:white;">Company Name</a><a style="color:#94d60a;background-color:white;">.</a>
      </h1>
    </header>
    <table width="95%" align="center" cellpadding="10" style="width:95%; background-color: #535659;">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td style="padding-left:15px">Case Number: 0000069</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <table cellpadding="10">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td style="padding-left:35px">Date Opened: 10/31/2017 at 2:13 PM</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <table width="95%" align="center" cellpadding="10" style="width:95%;background-color:white;">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td style="padding-left:20px;">
            You are receiving this email because your case has been updated. Your case details and any updates can be found below this message.
            <br /> If you wish to post a comment to the case you can simply reply to this email and your case will be updated. If you would like to include a screenshot or relevant log files you can do so by including them in your reply.
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="center" style="text-align: center;">
            <span class="container">
            <ul class="progressbar">
              <li class="done">Open</li>
              <li class="done">In Progress</li>
              <li class="done">With Engineering</li>
              <li class="done">Resolution Provided</li>
              <li>Closed</li>
            </ul>
          </span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="padding-left:20px;">
            In order to proceed with your case we will need additional information or clarification on the reported issue. Please provide the requested information within the next 4 days. If no response is received during this time we will temporarily archive your
            case. Once you are ready to continue with simply reply to one of the case emails.
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <td>
          <table cellpadding="5" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td width="150" style="width:150px;background-color:#bbbcbc;padding-left:20px;border-left:10px solid #d9d9d6;">
                  <span style="background-color:#bbbcbc;">Subject</span>
                </td>
                <td width="350" style="width:350px;border:1px solid #bbbcbc;">TICKET TITLE HERE</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td width="150" style="width:150px; background-color:#bbbcbc;padding-left:20px;border-left:10px solid #d9d9d6;">
                  <span style="background-color:#bbbcbc;">Description</span>
                </td>
                <td width="350" style="width:350px;border:1px solid #bbbcbc;">TICKET DESCRIPTION HERE</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <table width="95%" align="center" cellpadding="10" style="width:95%;text-align:center;background-color:#bbbcbc;">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="padding-top:10px">Company Name: Company Address</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</html>
```

However, when run on different devices and clients, these results ensue:

iPhone 6S Plus @ Outlook:[image]

Google Pixel 2 XL @ Gmail:[image]

iPhone 6s Plus @ Mail (default app):[image]

What is leading to these inconsistencies? How can I address them?
Thank you so much in advance for any help.

Comment: In my experience, email clients don't behave properly - I presume their implementations don't follow any kind of standard - with separate CSS declarations; when I was doing HTML flyers for a client, I had to use all inline CSS.

Comment: @MatthewMoore I'm very new to HTML and CSS alike - can you elaborate on how I could do that? I embedded the CSS by using a <style> tag at the top of the editor I am using. I do not have the option of using a CSS file that I can just refer to in the <style>, unfortunately.

Comment: Formatting email templates for email is a real pain. I found a service that does it really well and it's open source so you don't have to use a paid service like `limus` or anything like that https://mjml.io/. I use one of these templates and modify it a bit to look how I want it to look and then simply copy it into my html file and my email looks flawless across all email clients every time.

Comment: For information on inline styles, https://www.quackit.com/css/inline_style_sheets.cfm gives a quick rundown of it. (It's ugly, unmaintainable, and bad practice in normal circumstances). But also @Curious13 has posed a good - probably better - suggestion too.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that each email client behaves differently, and each supports a varying number of css-styles.  There is a pretty comprehensive list of styles and which browsers/versions support which on [Campaign Monitor's Ultimate Guide to CSS](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/).

The answer to how you address them is quite complicated.  Each version of each client is going to have a long list of tips & tricks to make it work better, and that might just break your CSS in other clients.  Here are just a few aspects of how to work with outlook:

https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/how-to-create-excellent-emails-for-outlook-com/

https://group-mail.com/html-email/tips-to-create-html-email-that-works-with-all-email-clients-part-1/

https://templates.mailchimp.com/development/css/outlook-conditional-css/

The best way to see how your email will behave in multiple browsers is to use a service like [Litmus](https://litmus.com/) which has a trial period so you can compare it to free options like [mjml.io](https://mjml.io/)